# KnockoutJS not updating view

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am having an issue with Knockout which seems a bit puzzling.

I have a list of contacts, which I want to bind to the UI (observableArray).
However I do not need the items themselves to each be observable, since they are only updated through a dialog box and I don't need each field tracked separately.

I have the following jsFiddle to demonstrate my issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/EsgGg/12/

```
var c = contacts()[0];
c.name="James";
contacts.splice( 0, 1, c ); 
// the contacts observableArray is now correct but the UI is unchanged
```

For some reason the splice method does not update the View??

Thanks in advance.

I really think that Knockout should allow a trigger('change') or some other method on observables to make this type of thing easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout has a change trigger on observables. It's called `valueHasMutated()`

```
contacts.valueHasMutated();
```

---

But in fact you are better off if every value that shows on the screen (and is subject to occasional change) is an actual observable in your view model.

```
contacts()[0].name("James");  // done
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on that method.
The problem with mapping every single field is that updating them from the server with JSON much more difficult.  Also why monitor the values if they will never change individually?

1. open edit Dialog (jQueryUI) 
2. copy contact values into form inside Dialog
3. when save button is clicked, read form values into JS object
4. replace entry in contacts list.

the other way for #4 would be 
iterate over each JS property and call the observable
each time invoking a render on the page.

Comment: That's what [the mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) has been created for. With only very little effort it does all the mapping you want. It can even only map half of your JSON, if you configure it to do so. It also takes care of un-mapping everything if you want to update the server.

Comment: You beat me to the comment about the mapping plugin. @DavidMedlock, don't you need the properties to be observable for step #2 in your comment? If the properties are not observable, how will knockout know that the values in your form's textboxes has changed, and to update the properties in your viewmodel accordingly?

Comment: Tomalak: Thanks for the heads up on ko.mapping.  

@danludwig: I can certainly do binding on the dialog with ko.applyBindings each time the dialog is opened, (wouldn't I also have to  call resetAll?? when the dialog is closed?).

Now you have the problem of the "Cancel" button.  

Because I am binding values in the view(DOM) with values in my viewModel (unnecessarily imo) , i have to hack around the transaction nature of a dialog.